# HANA into native android?

Tags: android, jdbc, hana, android-studio-2.3

I am creating an Android application in Android Studio 2.3.3. I am about to implement a HANA SQL database query and display a diagram. I created the application, tried to include `ngdbc.jar` file in several ways:

1. Add as a jar module,
2. Add as a library (copied into `libs` folder),
3. Project structure, dependencies, added this jar file.

However I could not make it work. I have imported `java.sql.*;` (possibly well, since it's not red or grey)

```
Try {
Class.Forname("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver"); // <- this code crashing my application. 
} catch (Exception e) {
// handling
}
```

After `Class.Forname` I would create a `Connection conn` variable with the needed details about the physical HANA SQL database but the code crashes beforehand.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: what kind of Exception is thrown by your code?

Answer (score 0):

The official docs can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/52715f71adba4aaeb480d946c742d1f6/2.0.00/en-US/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html)

```
Connection connection = null;
  try {                  
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:sap://myhdb:30715/?autocommit=false",myname,mysecret);                  
  } catch (SQLException e) {
     System.err.println("Connection Failed. User/Passwd Error?");
     return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can use android application to access HANA backend database directly via JDBC.

You perhaps need a middle layer (like web server) to provide the REST or some Http access API,  in the API impl, you can use standard JDBC to access HANA database.
then android app can access the API to access the HANA finally.